# Delete aws event source mappings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile, aws-lambda

So I have a make file that deletes an event source mapping for a lambda

```
.PHONY: delete-event-source-mapping
delete-event-source-mappings: ## Delete event source mappings for project lambda.
    aws lambda delete-event-source-mapping \
        --uuid <guid>
```

But this is hard coded to a single UUID. How can I delete all the even source mappings that are attached to a lambda?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the target to list all event-source-mappings and deleting all of the GUIDS that were listed.

```
.PHONY: delete-event-source-mapping
delete-event-source-mappings: ## Delete event source mappings for project lambda.
    $(eval UUIDS := $(shell aws lambda list-event-source-mappings \
        --function-name <function_name> \
        --event-source <function_arn> | grep "UUID" | awk -F'"' '{print $$4}'))
    for mapping_uuid in $(UUIDS); do \
        aws lambda delete-event-source-mapping --uuid $$mapping_uuid; \
    done
```

If you wanted to delete by another criteria (other then just being attached to the target lambda) you'll need to add some parsing logic after the list portion. Eventually I plan to add a filter by event source (like, say, from S3 or Kinesis).

Comment: Do you know if there any way of doing this from the AWS Console?

Comment: I don't know of a programmatic way from the AWS console that deletes all event source mappings. That's part of why I made a make file to do stuff like this.